# return old and latest date from a column in a table as a single column with two rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on postgresql database server. Can i get min and max date from a column in a single column? I have two tables,i want to get the min and max date stored in table1 cfrange column which is of type character varying. table1 and table2 is mapped using sid. 
table1:

```
sid  cfrange  

100   3390
101   8000
102   5/11/2010
103   11/12/2016
104   01/03/2016
105   4000
106   4000
107   03/12/2017
108   03/11/2016
109   4/04/2018
110   10/12/2016
```

table2:

```
sid  description

102  success
103  success
104  Proceeding
107  success
108  success
```

Please see the code below:

```
select min(cfrange::date) as min_cf,
max(cfrange::date) as max_cf from (select table1.sid, table1.cfrange::date as cfrange from table1 inner join table2 on table1.sid = table2.sid) tt;
```

I want the out put as below:

```
min_max
2010-11-05
2017-12-03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just union together two subqueries, one which finds the minimum and one which finds the max:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT
       t1.sid,
       t1.cfrange::date AS cfrange
   FROM table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON t1.sid = t2.sid
)
SELECT MIN(t.cfrange::date) AS min_max
FROM cte t
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(t.cfrange::date)
FROM cte t
ORDER BY min_max
```

If you want a single query which you could, for example, run directly from your Java code, then you can embed the CTE directly, e.g.

```
SELECT MIN(t.cfrange::date) AS min_max
FROM
(
   SELECT
       t1.sid,
       t1.cfrange::date AS cfrange
   FROM table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON t1.sid = t2.sid
) t
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(t.cfrange::date)
FROM
(
   SELECT
       t1.sid,
       t1.cfrange::date AS cfrange
   FROM table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON t1.sid = t2.sid
) t
ORDER BY min_max
```

Comment: can i write that as a query instead of function/procedure?

Comment: @user4103233 The answer I gave you _is_ a query, not a function/proc.  If you don't want to use a CTE or don't understand it, then just replace `cte t` with the body of the CTE definition.  I would probably use a CTE in this case, because it makes the query much easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, accepted the answer but still want  to know can we write in more simpler way as i need to use this query in my java code..The query which i have posted can we modify it slightly to get the expected output. select min(cfrange::date) as min_cf,
max(cfrange::date) as max_cf from (select table1.sid, table1.cfrange::date as cfrange from table1 inner join table2 on table1.sid = table2.sid) tt;

Comment: Please see my edited post above, I want to write the same query without using joins in my query. suggestions would be helpful.thanks.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is with using joins, and in any case my answer addresses your original question.  If you need a different query you should open a new question.  Stack Overflow is not an ongoing discussion where the question keeps changing.